# Intersection of std::vectors sorted according to different functions

Tags: c++, stl, vector, intersection

I have std::vectors of ints v1, v2, v3, ... v10. Each with a few 100,000s of elements. Each vector is sorted by a different factor (so there are 10 factor functions f1, f2, ... f10). So though they are sorted by themselves, relative to each other they are unsorted.

I want to find the intersection of these 10 vectors and I want to the output to be sorted according one of the factor. For e.g. the result should be sorted according to f1. So when I pass these 10 vectors to that intersect-sort function along with the factor function, I will get an output vector that has only the elements that are present in all vectors, sorted according to f1. What is the best way to do this operation?

Comment: Are all the vectors sorted according to the same order?

Comment: No. There are in different order. The functions according to which each vector is sorted is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `std::set_intersection()` a couple of time. I think you'd need two temporary vectors used alternatingly to store the results. If you want to do it with just one pass of each vector, you'd just use a generalized version of it possibly keeping a priority queue of the current smallest value.